# Why '42' is the preferred number when indicating something random?

Tags: history, numbers

I have seen this on the SO on many times. Whenever a question is vague and the question is asking some magical answer somebody or the other leaves a comment saying answer is 42. Even a book I am reading right now uses '42' as the number whenever it wants demonstrate some basic concept using an integer. So is there any history behind it or it is just a coincidence?

Comment: Now that Fishtoaster's answer has reached 42 upvotes, I'm locking this to preserve the awesomeness forever.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's the answer to [Life, The Universe, and Everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe_and_Everything_.2842.29) from Douglas Adams' [*Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

Comment: I thought everyone knew this. :(

Comment: @Nathan - Sorry, not everyone reads Douglas Adams.

Comment: In some imaginably far distant future it may be true, lol.

Comment: If I ever write a programming language I will allow for base 13 integers. Then `6 * 9` will finally be 42, and the universe will instantly be replaced with something vastly more complex!! I've a feeling that this has already happened...

Comment: @Moshe, well they should.

Comment: Why in the world is this a :-(, @Nathan Taylor?  Surely you're not suggesting that all programmers subscribe to some single monoculture.

Comment: @Andy Lester it's not just a single monoculture, it is *the* monoculture.

Comment: I have not read the book but I know the answer to Life, The Universe, and Everything is 42.

Answer (score 17):

As [Fishtoaster mentioned](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/507/why-42-is-the-preferred-number-when-indicating-something-random/509#509), the number *42* has gained pop-culture status via Douglas Adams's *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*, but its true origins are from [Lewis Carroll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#In_the_works_of_Lewis_Carroll) (from whom Adams gained occasional inspiration).

Comment: Some of the examples in that article are pretty sketchy, especially where it starts getting into mathematical extrapolation and alternate base numbering.